# Error while using Retrofit 2 ProtoBuf converter

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, retrofit2

i'm trying to use ProtoConverterFactory. The .proto files i'm using looks like this:

Foo.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

import "bar.proto";

message CommonProtoMessage {
    required string messageName = 1;
    required bytes messageBody = 2;
}

message ResponseRequestMessage {

    optional Request1 request1 = 1;
    optional Response1 response1 = 2;
    optional Request2 request2 = 3;
    optional DoSomething dosomething = 4;
    optional GetResponseRequest getResponseRequest = 5;
    optional RequestCompletedNotification requestCompleted = 6;
}

message MessageWrapper {

    optional int64 requestId = 1;

    optional ResponseRequestMessage responseRequestMessage = 2;
    optional CommonProtoMessage commonMessage = 3;
}
```

Bar.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Request1 {
    required string username = 1;
    required string password = 2;
    required string workstation = 3;
}

message Response1 {
    required int64 id = 1;
}

message Request2 {
    required int64 id = 1;
}

message DoSomething {
    required int64 id = 1;
}

message GetResponseRequest {
    required int64 id1 = 1;
    required int64 id2 = 2;
}

message RequestCompletedNotification {
    required int64 id1 = 1;
    required int64 id2 = 2;
}
```

I compiled these files using wire library into several java classes. After that i tried to send request to server using Retrofit.

Retrofit builder:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(ProtoConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

But my app crashes with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{**activity name**}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Unable     to     create @Body converter for class .proto.Foo 
(parameter #1)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate 
RequestBody converter for class 
proto.ngs.vms.messages.proto.MessageWrapper.

Tried:

* retrofit2.BuiltInConverters

* retrofit2.converter.protobuf.ProtoConverterFactory
```

From this error i got that Retrofit could not use proto converter for my compiled classes

I tried to find some info on Retrofit and Protobuf but i did not find anything useful

Comment: Found anything?